# Desktop pinch zoom

Tags: dell, touchpad, unity-tweak-tool

I am using Dell XPS 15 and have pinch zoom configured with Ubuntu Unity Tweak. How can I reconfigure it to get the same result with touchpad instead of keys?
Tool does not recognize gestures. But I can scroll with two fingers and zoom web pages in Firefox with ctrl and touchpad.

Screenshot of my Unity Tweak Tool:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **[Compiz Config Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/)**
2. **Accessibility**
3. Enable **Enhanced Zoom Desktop**
4. In **Zoom in/out** Tab chose you favorite setting.
5. Recommended setting to **Zoom In** `button 4` + `Bottom Edge`
6. For **Zoom Out** `button 5` + `Bottom Edge`

[image]

> Hence Button 4 & 5 `Scroll` **top down** and **down top**

Comment: How to set pinch gesture?

Comment: @AskhatNuriddinov that is what i recommend number 5 and 6

Comment: It is scrolling. I want to get pinch gesture like here https://friendsofmaconfb.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/gestures.png

Comment: yes i know sir on my ubuntu their's no difference between scroll and pinch are you tried it ??

Comment: @AskhatNuriddinov on my system -> mouse&touchpad -> i enable two finger scroll may you you use edge scrolling

Comment: I tried and sometimes it works and sometimes not. I think there is difference but pinching sometimes is recognized as scrolling.

Comment: honestly i don't know  if they different or no  but i use always and work fine

Comment: if you want another solution you can try touch egg but i don't use it before
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchegg

Comment: @AskhatNuriddinov can you try button 6 and 7 instead ??